# how to modify my custom properties file in android

Tags: android, file, properties, apk

i am using a properties file to get the url of various webservices i am calling from my android. I want to provide a congiguration option so that ip address for web service can be modified.
how to proceed ?

i have a resource folder in src folder which have the following values 
update=http://10.52.165.226:50000/android/rest/get/updateSfc
ShopOrder=http://10.52.165.226:50000/android/rest/getShopOrder/bySite?site=

i am using resource bundle to use this values in android.?

I am thinking of reading the file and replace all occrence of Ip address. how to rad the properties file and edit it in android

Comment: Also it help those others who faces the same issue. By viewing the accepted answers. You can accept the answer by clicking on check image given right side of the answer.

Comment: If you are not satisfied with all the given answers. Even then you must have found the solution by of your own. post that and accept your answer. But try to keep question coupled with accepted answer. I know this all is obvious. But sometime its better to be verbose :)

Answer (score 8):

Here is a complete solution for you to use .properties file in your project.

1 Create a file named app.properties in assets folder of your android project

2 edit the file and write with in properties that you want to use for example as

```
test=success
```

And Save file

3 Write this Method with in your Activity Class

```
  private Properties loadPropties() throws IOException {
  String[] fileList = { "app.properties" };
  Properties prop = new Properties();
  for (int i = fileList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     String file = fileList[i];
     try {
        InputStream fileStream = getAssets().open(file);
        prop.load(fileStream);
        fileStream.close();
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Ignoring missing property file " + file);
     }
  }
  return prop;
  }
```

4 With in OnCreate Method  write some thing like this

```
     Properties prop = null; 
     try {
        prop = loadPropties();
     } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception", e);
     }
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result " + prop.getProperty("test"),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

5 add necessary imports

Hope this helps :)

Comment: More good will be if you define your own Application class within your project and loads properties from there.

Comment: i have the properties file in the src folder .Can this approach be applied there???

Comment: No, Also it wouldn't be wise to keep property file in src folder. The assets folder is their for this purpose only

Answer (score 3):

Read about [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) in Android and more specifically [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). For more complete usage of saving user preferences, read about the [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html).

A tutorial on using Shared Preferences can be found [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-application-preferences/)

Answer (score 2):

Resources, Assets and other files/folders that form the part of Apk cannot be modified.You can use a [database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)  for depending on nos of rows that you will use